# Application for Schengen visa when bank statement is not available

Tags: schengen, uk, france

I would be going to UK and from there I would like to apply for a Schengen visa where the port of entry would be France. My friend who is a student stays in Lyon and I would be visiting him. However for Schengen I would have to show 6 months payslip which I would not have as I want to do it by next month. So how can the schengen be done. Please help.

Comment: You generally cannot apply for a Schengen visa in the UK unless you live in the UK.  In general, you must apply for the Schengen visa at the consulate which serves your place of residence.  In addition, the primary way to determine which country you need to apply to is the *main destination* of your trip to Schengen, not the port of entry.  If you provide more details about your country of residence and your planned itinerary, you may get some more useful advice.

Comment: @phoog The last time I looked, Lyon _was_ in France.

Comment: Bank statements or pay slips? You had no bank account three months ago? How come? Are you a student or did you just get your first official job? Also, what are your citizenship and country of residence?

Comment: Have you already got a visa for the UK? What did you submit to the British consulate? The rules are distinct and the French consulate will reach a decision independently but evidence that's good enough for the UK should generally be good enough for a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, pay slips are not a requirement *per se* but having sufficient financial means and providing some guarantees that you will return to your country of residence are.

For the financial means, you can for example submit bank statements instead of pay slips. Your friend should also obtain an official invitation ([*attestation d'accueil*](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F2191.xhtml)), which would technically reduce the amount of money you need to cover your needs during the trip and generally establish the purpose of your trip.

For the guarantees, also submit your work contract or maybe something that shows you have been granted time off work and will return to your job afterwards. You haven't mentioned any but property and other ties to your country of residence can also help.

Of course, if your finances did not look good a few months ago (usually I thought it was three, not six) and your situation does not appear to be stable, it is possible that the visa would be refused but trying to hide it by omitting some key documents would make a negative outcome just as likely so there is little point in doing that.

Also, your question mentions “pay slips” but the title says “bank statement”, which ones are missing? No job history is bad but no financial history is worse. Unless you have a very good explanation, if you had no bank account at all three months ago (and as common as it is in some countries), it's going to be extremely difficult to get a short-stay visa. If that's the situation you are in, it would be wise to wait a few more months to establish you have a stable source of income. Otherwise, submit the bank statements in any case.

Finally, as @phoog explained, applying in London is generally not possible if you are not a resident in England, Wales or Northern Ireland. You should apply in the consulate in charge of your current place of residence instead. See also [Can we apply for a Schengen tourist visa while visiting another country on a short-stay visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london) and [Can I apply for Schengen visa from London as foreigner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47223/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-from-london-as-foreigner)