# French visa confusion

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, south-africa

I currently hold a multi entry Schengen visa that is valid until May. I have used up my 90 days for this 6 month period staying with my parents who have recently emigrated tho France.

I am now moving to the UK from South Africa at the beginning of January. I have two questions. As I am leaving my home country will I be able to apply for a Schengen visa whilst in the UK once my current visa expires and if not will I be able to apply for a second visa while my first one is still valid while I am in my home country?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Apply for a visa in the UK once you live there (i.e. have some sort of long-stay visa or permit, not merely a [visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview)). That's the regular procedure for foreign residents in the UK who need a visa to visit the Schengen area and is not a problem at all. Since you said that you are “moving” to the UK, I assume you will have some sort of resident status there and this would seem to be the easiest solution for you.
- Ask a French consulate in the UK to consider your application even if you don't live there. The difference is that you have to explain why they should and they might refuse but that's not impossible, see e.g. [Can I apply for Schengen visa from London as foreigner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47223/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-from-london-as-foreigner) and [Can we apply for a Schengen tourist visa while visiting another country on a short-stay visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london)
- Apply to renew your *multiple-entry* visa up to six months before it expires (article 9 of the [Schengen Visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018)). Rules for single-entry visas are more restrictive and having used your 90 days could in this case lead to a refusal but in your situation, with a multiple-entry visa and a legitimate reason for repeated visits, applying now in South Africa should be OK. There is not much time left for this, though.