# Travelling when my Schengen visa expires: Can I renew it in a country where I am not a resident?

Tags: schengen, visa-extensions, schengen-visas

I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa that is valid until December 2016. I will arrive in  The Netherlands on September and will leave on November BUT I need to go back to The Netherlands on February 2017. By that time the validity of my visa is expired. And the thing is, I will not be in my home country on the month which it will expire... lets say for example I will be in Thailand. Can I apply for a Schengen visa in Thailand - NOT my country of residence? Or Can I extend my visa there?

Or while I am in The Netherlands, can I extend the validity of my visa?

Comment: @MichaelHampton This question is very similar and highly relevant but there are some details in the current question that raised the possibility of another solution so I went ahead and answered it anyway.

Comment: Are you aware of [the 90/180 rule](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work?rq=1)? You haven't provided enough details (exact dates) to know if your plan is within the bounds of the rules or not but given that September-November is three months and February is only two months later, it seems possible that you would not be allowed back in the Schengen area so soon, even if your visa was still valid.

Comment: @Relaxed Well, this user is really asking two separate questions. I'm pretty sure the other question has been well covered here before also.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's not really the most important thing, the difference is that this is about a *renewal* for a *multiple-entry* visa. The OP seems concerned about the date of expiry of her current visa, which is not that important. As I explain below, she could really apply for a new Schengen visa for a her next trip at any time between July 2016 and Feburary 2017, which is a lot more flexibility than she seems to realize. Incidentally, it also makes it much more difficult to argue that she could not apply in her country of residence and thus qualifies for an exemption under article 6(2).

Comment: I edited the title of the question to make the differences more salient.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you cannot *extend* your Schengen visa anywhere else than within the Schengen area but extending a visa is only possible in very specific situations (e.g. you are stuck in a hospital). So in your case, you will actually need to apply for a renewal/new visa (and *that* is generally not possible from within the area).

Generally speaking, you should apply for a visa from the relevant consulate serving your current place of residence – and nowhere else, not even another consulate in the same country – but there are some limited exceptions. For example, if you have good reasons (say documented professional or familial obligations) that force you to be out of the country for a long period of time before your next trip to the Schengen area, you could try to convince another consulate to consider your application. But mere convenience or a holiday in Thailand would not be enough typically.

See the following questions for details about that:

- [Can I apply for a Schengen visa at a country where I'm not a citizen? If so, under what conditions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-country-where-im-not-a-citizen-if-so-und)
- [Can we apply for a Schengen tourist visa while visiting another country on a short-stay visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london)
- [Can I apply for Schengen visa from London as foreigner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47223/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-from-london-as-foreigner)
- [Can I get an appointment at a French consulate different than the one assigned to my state?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/can-i-get-an-appointment-at-a-french-consulate-different-than-the-one-assigned-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But in your case, it's important to note that there is no special significance to the date of expiry of your current visa. You can in fact apply for your next visa before that and the consulate will simply issue a visa starting some time after the end of your current visa (either directly after it or at the date of your next planned trip). If you did not have a multiple-entry visa, you would only be allowed to apply during the three months prior to the next trip but when renewing a multiple-entry visa, it's at any time during the six months *before the expiry of the current visa*, cf. article 9(1) of the Schengen Visa code.

This means that you have a great deal of flexibility and it doesn't matter whether you are out of the country during the month during which your visa expires or immediately before the trip. That's not impediment and also would not be a good reason for a consulate to make an exception because you can actually apply at any time between between now and February.